# How to install kubernetes offline on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernetes offline on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS in VirtualBox using internal network.

I am installing kubernetes, following the guide [Install Docker](https://gist.github.com/onuryilmaz/89a29261652299d7cf768223fd61da02) step by step.

I installed docker 18.09 version, docker images and kubeadm/kubectl/kubelet/cni.
But when I input command `kubeadm init`, it stopped in the spot pulling docker images.

I wonder if there is a way fixing this problem or another way to install kubernetes offline on Ubuntu.

Below, I attached images about `kubeadm init` error and docker images.

Let me know your experience or websites.

[image]

[image]